# How to get rolling MIN number for all rest rows(include current rows) BY category

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data table as below, which sorted by data, route_number and sequence.

```
Delivery Date   Order_ID    Route_Number    Stop #  Sequence    Min Stop#   Formula 
12/11/2017         Z11         100201         2        1           1    MIN(D2:$D$6)
12/11/2017         Z12         100201         1        2           1    MIN(D3:$D$6)
12/11/2017         Z13         100201         3        3           3    MIN(D4:$D$6)
12/11/2017         Z14         100201         5        4           4    MIN(D5:$D$6)
12/11/2017         Z15         100201         4        5           4    MIN(D6:$D$6)
```

What I am trying to do is in my SQL query, how can I get the column **Min Stop#** as I can in the excel.

The logic is: give me the min stop# from current row to all rest rows in same  route_number,and delivery date, I am thinking something like Partition by delivery_date, route_number.

Does anyone has some ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
min(stop) over (partition by route_number, delivery_date
order by sequence rows between current row and unbounded following)
```

or

```
min(stop) over (partition by route_number, delivery_date
order by sequence desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
```

which can be simplified to

```
min(stop) over (partition by route_number, delivery_date
order by sequence desc) m2
```

because `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` is the default window when you use ordering in over clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use `min` window function.

```
select t.*,min(stop) over(partition by route_number,delivery_date
                          order by sequence rows between current row 
                          and unbounded following) as min_stop
from tbl t
```